# SQL Code - Cannot add or update a child row

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have created a database and added tables to it no bother, I am trying to add data into the tables but keep getting the error:

ERROR 1452: (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`music`,`track`, CONSTRAINT `track_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`genre_id`) REFERENCES `genre`(`genre_id`))

Tables:

```
create table genre
(
genre_id int not null auto_increment,
genre_name varchar(10),
primary key (genre_id)
);

create table artist
(
artist_id int not null auto_increment,
artist_name varchar(20),
primary key (artist_id)
);

create table track   
(
track_id int not null auto_increment,
artist_id int not null,
genre_id int not null,
track_name varchar(50),
primary key (track_id),
foreign key (genre_id) references genre (genre_id),
foreign key (artist_id) references artist (artist_id)
);

create table location 
(
location_id int not null auto_increment,
location_name varchar(25),
primary key (location_id)
);

create table user 
(
user_id int not null auto_increment,
genre_id int not null,
location_id int not null,
user_fname varchar(10),
user_lname varchar(10),
user_age int,
user_gender bit,
primary key (user_id),
foreign key (genre_id) references genre (genre_id),
foreign key (location_id) references location (location_id)
);
```

The next line of code is where it causes the error and all other tracks are written like this so whatever the problem at this line will be my solution?

```
INSERT INTO `music`.`track`(`track_name`,`artist_id`,`genre_id`) VALUES 
('Next Episode',2,1);
```

Comment: You cannot add a row into `track` until the other tables have been populated with the corresponding records.  That is what `foreign key` relationships do.

Comment: You need a `genre` record with `genre_id` = 1 before you can insert a `track` record with `genre_id` = 1.

Comment: mysql> select * from genre;
+----------+------------+
| genre_id | genre_name |
+----------+------------+
|        1 | Hip Hop    |
|        2 | House      |
|        3 | Rock       |
|        4 | Metal      |
|        5 | Techno     |
|        6 | Indie      |
+----------+------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

genres already have an id